# How to check the below scenario in linq to sql?

Tags: linq-to-sql

**Users:**

```
userid   username               password
1        venkat reddy           sa
2        reddy                  as
3        re                     sa
```

**Location:**

```
id  userid             lat           lon
1     1                14.00       15.00
2     2                15.00       17.23
3     3                15.00       17.23
```

**Friends:**

```
id    userid      friendid            isActive
1      1            2                   true
1      2           1                    true
```

I need to query like if I pass `userid=1` and `username=re`, then I need to get all rows starting with `re` and if that user is already friend to that `userid` give status message like `already friend` and his username and userid. If a user is not a friend  as of now then give his details like username and userid.

Please tell me ....

Ex: userid =1   username=re

then I need output like

```
 <OutputResponse>
    <Response>
      <userid>2</userid>
      <username>reddy</username>
      <lat>15.00</lat>
      <lon>17.23</lon>
      <status>already friend</status>
    </Response>
    <Response>
      <userid>3</userid>
      <username>re</username>
      <lat>15.00</lat>
      <lon>17.23</lon>
      <status>not a friend as of now</status>
    </Response>
 </OutputResponse>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can start with something like this...

```
int userid=1;
string username="re";

var result=(from q in Users
                join qq in Location on q.id equals qq.userid
            where q.Username.StartsWith(username)       
             select new
            {
               userid=q.Id,
               username=q.Username,
               lat=l.lat,
               lon=l.lon,
               status=Friends.Where(z=>z.Friendid==q.Id&&z.Userid==userid).Count()>0?"already friend":"not a friend as of now"

            });
```